# Retirement Conversion to whole life insurance or not

Tags: retirement, life-insurance, whole-life

Both my husband and I had term life insurance policies that were convertible at age 60 to whole life. I am 67 and converted mine years ago. My younger husband is reaching the deadline date for conversion of his. He had $100,000 of term. Converting it to about $50,000 of whole life would cost about 124.00 a month. I am trying to figure out if that is a good idea.

We have no retirement, own a small business. Would it be wiser to take that money and use it to start a Roth IRA keeping only the term insurance to age 70?

I know it is late in the game but he will probably work another 10 years. I have been reading to educate myself but it is complicated and different sides have different opinions. The down side of whole life insurance seems to be that you have to die to get it... so if we need additional income in old age that would not happen unless we draw against the policy.

Any advice or help would be appreciated...so confused. Our 2 sons are grown and independent. If we pay premiums for 20 years he will have paid 29,000 for 50,000 of a pay out I figure. Is whole life a good idea for retirement?

Comment: No regular contributor to this site recommends Whole Life.  **Ever.**  The purpose of insurance is to pay out in case of disaster, but Whole Life tries to pretend to be a investment at the same time, which it does a bad job of.

Comment: "*Converting it to about 50,000*"... do you mean converting it to a $50K whole life policy?

Comment: "*Would it be wiser to take that money*"... the $124/month money you'd spend on WL?

Comment: @RonJohn there are situations where whole life makes sense, but the devil is in the details. I certainly am not in the camp of people here who have an allergy to whole life.

Comment: To this question I would ask if there is any purpose to this insurance? Do you still have dependents who would be terribly financially impacted if you were to pass. The need for life insurance wanes as one ages generally.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I was referring to converting his 100,000 that expires at age 70 to a 50,000 whole life. The option to do so is running out. Yes the 124.00 per month is for whole life (50,000) for my husband. I also have a whole life policy for 50,000 that costs slightly less. Should I dissolve them both and contribute the entire amount to a Roth maybe? We no longer have dependents. The purpose...I think my husband wanted to provide for me if he could not originally.

Comment: "*Should I dissolve them both and contribute the entire amount to a Roth maybe?*"  It's definitely something to think about.  What you you and husband think is the purpose of life insurance: money to replace income or as part of retirement planning, or a "savings account that someone else cashes in at death"?  Since your husband owns a small business, it would probably behoove you to contact an estate planning **attorney** (who presumably won't have a vested interest in selling you a life insurance policy.

Comment: Thanks again RonJohn. Well I think mostly as extra income if needed but we would like to have enough for final expenses also. We own our home.

Comment: Our agent just told me that if I cash my policy out now I will only get 4830 of the 8650 I have paid into it. Is this a good idea?